# XMLSerializer missing tags

Tags: java

I have a big problem with XMLSerializer... I use JSON lib (net.sf.json) and this is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xmlInputMsg =    "<state>\n" +
                                "    <appId>newID</appId>\n" +
                                "    <newDocuments>\n" +
                                "        <nameValues>\n" +
                                "            <name>test1</name>\n" +
                                "            <value>123456</value>\n" +
                                "        </nameValues>\n" +
                                "        <nameValues>\n" +
                                "            <name>test2</name>\n" +
                                "            <value>987654</value>\n" +
                                "        </nameValues>\n" +
                                "    </newDocuments>\n" +
                                "    <oldDocument>\n" +
                                "        <oldAppId>true</oldAppId>\n" +
                                "        <name>App</name>\n" +
                                "        <source>NA</source>\n" +
                                "    </oldDocument>\n" +
                                "</state>";
    String result = null;
    XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
    xmlSerializer.setForceTopLevelObject(true);
    result = XMLSerializer.class.toGenericString();     
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

My current output is:

> "state": {
>     "appId": "newID",
>     "newDocuments":   [
>           {
>         "name": "test1",
>         "value": "123456"
>       },
>           {
>         "name": "test2",
>         "value": "987654"
>       }
>     ],
>     "oldDocument":   {
>       "oldAppId": "true",
>       "name": "App",
>       "source": "NA"
>     }
>   }}

But I would like have this msg:

> {
>     "state": {
>       "appId": "newID",
>       "newDocuments": {
>         "nameValues": [
>           {
>             "name": "test1",
>             "value": "123456"
>           },
>           {
>             "name": "test2",
>             "value": "987654"
>           }
>         ]
>       },
>       "oldDocument": {
>         "oldAppId": "true",
>         "name": "App",
>         "source": "NA"
>       }
>   }}

Unfortunately now I missing tag **nameValues**. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: I think you are using wrong schema there: you actually don't have `nameValues` property on `newDocuments`, which is exactly why you aren't seeing it in output. There should be input along the lines of `<documents><nameValues><nameValuePair><name>name</name></value></nameValuePair></nameValues></documents>`

Comment: Thanks, now it is working properly!